# Emit a warning with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, code-coverage, ts-jest

I am wondering if Jest has an option for emitting a warning when thresholds are not met instead of an error? I haven't been able to find any documentation on the subject.

For example in my old karma tester runner using Instanbul reporter I would do the following:

```
  thresholds: {
    emitWarning: true,
    global: {
      statements: 85,
      lines: 85,
      branches: 85,
      functions: 85
    }
  }
```

Is there a similar option such as `emitWarning: true` in Jest?